# why DataFrame in pandas arrange number before string?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data1 = {'key':['b','b','a','c','a','a','b'], 'data':range(7)}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

it is arranged as data, then follow by key. Why it is not arranged in key, then data?

Do I need to specify the columns?

Comment: There is nothing special about the word "key". If you want to sort the dataframe by "key," then do it: `df1.sort_values('key')`. And you probably confuse "key" and index.

Comment: `data1` is a dictionary and hence its elements are not ordered.

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['key', 'data']) will give me the key follows by data.

but if I don't specify columns, then it returns data follows by key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data1` is a dictionary so the elements are stored in an [arbitrary order](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Now, the reason you see it in that specific order every time is because pandas [frame constructor](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/330b8c1c195174f729a1d2ee6f916ebd1579217e/pandas/core/frame.py#L446) do [sort the dictionary keys](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/793020293ee1e5fa023f45c12943a4ac51cc23d0/pandas/core/common.py#L247) if there is no explicit columns argument.

Constructor simply uses:

```
>>> sorted(['key', 'data'])
['data', 'key']
```

So you are going to get the same ordering of columns every time. You can (have to) give the columns argument explicitly to store them in the order you want.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['key', 'data'])
  key  data
0   b     0
1   b     1
2   a     2
3   c     3
4   a     4
5   a     5
6   b     6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`OrderedDict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the [**`collections`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#) library to ensure we keep the same order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data1 = OrderedDict({'key': ['b','b','a','c','a','a','b'], 'data': range(7)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1

  key  data
0   b     0
1   b     1
2   a     2
3   c     3
4   a     4
5   a     5
6   b     6
```